# Как произвести выборку данных из строк в столбцы?

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравуствуйте! Необходимо разбить данные на два столбца имеющих свои данные.

Имеется такая таблица:

[image: Текст]

А нужно получить вот такую:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ломаю голову уже 5 час. Идея пришла только с тем, что необходимо использовать ntile. Чтобы вывести по группно. Но все без результатно.

```
select min(id), max(id)
  from (
    select id, row_number() over(partition by ntl order by id) grp
      from (
        select id, ntile(2) over(order by id) ntl
          from sales
      )
  )
 group by grp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно и итоги с помощью ROLLUP

```
select coalesce(FullName,'total') personName
  ,sum(case when SaleData=2022 then SalesSum else 0 end) sale22
  ,sum(case when SaleData=2023 then SalesSum else 0 end) sale23
from sales
group by FullName
with ROLLUP
```

| personName | sale22 | sale23 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SalesPerson1 | 1000.0999755859375 | 1002.0999755859375 |
| SalesPerson2 | 0 | 1003.0999755859375 |
| SalesPerson3 | 1004.0999755859375 | 0 |
| total | 2004.199951171875 | 2005.199951171875 |

Comment: rollup то зачем?

Comment: Только для полноты :)

Answer (score 3):

Или так:

```
SELECT id,FullName,
SUM(CASE
  WHEN SaleData = 2023 THEN Sum ELSE 0 END
) AS '2023',
SUM(CASE
  WHEN SaleData = 2024 THEN Sum ELSE 0 END
) AS '2024'
FROM sales
GROUP BY FullName;
```

Но как-то MySQL бледно выглядит без итоговых таблиц, потому что в других СУБД можно написать так:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Table1.[Sum]) AS TotalSum
SELECT Table1.[FullName]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.[FullName]
PIVOT Table1.[SaleData];
```

Comment: прям во всех других так можно, или приведен диалект какой-то одной СУБД ?

Comment: @teran слово "всех" вы сами вставили. Код из Access.

Comment: тогда так и напишите, что во многих СУБД есть пивот, в части из них он выглядит достаточно просто, как в вашем примере, а в другой части в общем случае придется писать динамический SQL, чтобы учесть произвольные годы.

Comment: @teran Я думаю, вашего комментария будет достаточно.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тому, что вы описали, вы хотите это

```
SELECT s.FullName, min(s.Sum), max(s.Sum)
FROM sales s
GROUP by s.FullName
```